# For which values of $m$ is $m$-partition hard?

Tags: np-complete, partitions, colorings

Consider the following reduction: $m$-colouring to $m$-partition.

Define an $m$-partition as: Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ and an integer $j$. Does there exist a partition of the vertices into $m$ parts $\{V_1, V_2, \ldots , V_m\}$ such that at least $j$ of the edges have their endpoints in different parts of the partition?

I was able to come up with the reduction, but now I'm stuck at this question:

What I need to find is the values of $m$ where the reduction implies that $m$-Partition is NP-complete?

Comment: For what values of m is m-coloring NP-complete?  What research have you done on that?

Comment: Hmm, well if m=2 in the m-colouring problem, then the graph is bipartite and solvable in polynomial time, i.e. not NP-Complete. I believe the max value for m is actually 4, since every map can be colored in just 4 colors without touching. For m=3 the problem is NP-Complete. For m=4, well that is always possible. That can be solved in O(1).

Comment: @Matthew Not quite: the problem is still NP-complete for 4 colors. When you say "a map" you mean a planar graph and that's true, but in general it's still hard.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity) has the answer on the corresponding graph colouring problem.

Comment: @Juho Thanks for the correction! Can any graph be colored in just 4 colors?

Comment: @Matthew No, consider the complete graph on 5 vertices, or more generally any graph with a large clique.

Comment: @Juho My mind is blown. I was too narrow-minded on that map rule-of-4. Yep, a clique of size n would need n different colors. Also, a clique of > 4 can not be represented by a map. That cleared a lot up for me, thanks!

Comment: @Juho Looks like the m-colouring problem is just the max clique problem. They should make a classification for similar problems like this. (sarcasm)

Comment: @Matthew To blow your mind even more, they are not the same problems. A graph without a large clique can still require a lot of colors :-) Have a look at the [Mycielskians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian).

Comment: @Juho Wow! Where should I look to learn about graph properties to become as powerful as you? I find trial and error to be exhausting. For example, it would take me maybe ~5-30 mins of random graph examples to discover what you just stated. Do you simply have good understanding and memory of the properties of graphs? Is it that you have enough practice with NP reductions that these come natural to you? What would you recommend I look into?

Comment: @Matthew Do as many exercises as you can, there's no substitute for that. Play around with graphs and reductions and you will improve over time. I don't have a particular resource in mind - there's a lot of books and other material that is good.

Answer (score 1):

The $1$-partition problem is trivial, since there is only one possible partition.

The $2$-partition problem is the same as MAX-CUT, which is known to be NP-complete.

For $m > 2$, the $m$-partition problem is NP-complete by reduction from $m$-coloring, which is NP-complete for that range of $m$.

Comment: so m>=2 is your answer?

Comment: My answer is just what I wrote.